# GWT Button onClick() return a value

Tags: java, gwt

I need to create 2 generic button called yes and no with 2 return 0 if no 1 if yes. I see the onclick method is void and not return int, how can i do?

```
YesButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            ??? result ??

        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to elaborate what scenario you are trying to address. The question indicates you are not familiar with how event handlers work.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by returning 1 or 0? whatever is the functionality do you want to achieve, can't you do that same in onClick method?

Comment: i must reuse many time this buttons for various scenario, i need to receive the vaue and after pass the value to relative method. in my webapp usually i need to do a selection to accept of refuse command

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to do it. Not knowing your specific requirement makes it a little hard, but I'll venture a suggestion. First define a controller/mediator/whachamacallit with the operations that the view can perform:

```
public interface MyListener
{
    void onYesClick();
    void onNoClick();
}
```

(Could be a concrete class also, but yes and no clicking seems very generic, so we could reuse that elsewhere)

In your view class you would then have

```
public class MyView
{
    private MyListener listener;

    private Button yesButton = new Button( "yessir!" );
    private Button noButton = new Button( "no way!" );

    public MyView( MyListener listener ) { this.listener = listener; }

    yesButton.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) 
        {
            listener.onYesClick(); // similarly .onNoClick() for the "No" button
        }
    } );

    // etc
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps you a bit further.

Comment: i have another method that  wait the reslt of my selection (yes or no) how can i do with onYesClick method?

Comment: Have the class in which your method is implement `MyListener` and pass the instance to the view constructor. It is *very* hard to help you more without knowing more about your code and structure...

Comment: i need to create a simple panel with 2 button yes and no i can call other menthod , the panel show if i click yes sentd 1 to the method

Comment: I must create a personalize confirm panel. Then click on a button of my web app I need to show this panel (yes or no) when I click it is returned to method to the information that has been pressed, irrespective of the operation that must be made.